# Both Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA not starting on Ubuntu 14.04 (very similar error messages)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04

I'm asking about both IDEs on the same thread because I know Android Studio is built on IDEA and the error messages are very similar, so I think the issues are related.

I get the following error message when trying to run `studio.sh`:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class  
-Xms256m 
-Xmx1280m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 
-da 
-Djna.nosys=true 
-Djna.boot.library.path=       # Note: this field has no value in the output
-Djna.debug_load=true 
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true 
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Yes, `bootstrap.jar` does exist, and I've tried setting the permissions as detailed in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631004/cant-launch-android-studio-in-linux-getting-this-error-error-could-not-find-o) but that doesn't help.

This is what I get when I run `idea.sh`:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

In case this helps, the output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

StackOverflow and AskUbuntu are saturated with people having similar problems, but none of them have been able to help me so far. I've tried reinstalling the IDEs, I've tried changing permissions, I've tried changing values in the `idea64.vmoptions` file, and *nothing* has worked. I'm completely at a loss of what to do right now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happens to run into a similar problem: I managed to solve this issue. I created a `idea64.vmoptions` file in `~/IntelliJIdea2016.2` with the following content:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

After creating this file and restarting my Terminal, I can now run Android Studio and IDEA without issues.